# HTML Video player is malfunctioning for some files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

[image: Browser errors]

From the above image i have a video file while i am trying to retrieve the video `->` these issues are coming `->` only for specific files it is happening what could be the possible issue..?

i am appending video data with jquery ajax response:

```
$("#videoData").append('<video width="75%" class="center-block" 
                        controls autoplay style="max-width: 60em;">
                        <source style="max-width: 60em;" src="'+path+'" type="video/mp4">
                        '+response["videoName"]+'</video>');
```

Inside the path video location will come from start.`(http://website.com/uploads/file.mp4)`

My html is this:

```
<div id="videoData">     </div>
```

My php to store the file is this:

```
$videoPath      = '../uploads/course_videos/'.$coursename;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['course_video']['name']); $i++) {
$videofilename      =   $_FILES["course_video"]["name"][$i];
$videofilename      =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$videofilename);
$targetVideo = $videoPath ."/". $videofilename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["course_video"]["tmp_name"][$i], $targetVideo)
}
```

All the file is uploading properly in the folder but i don't know why Few videos are not coming

I thought the file may be corrupted but when i download the same file again from server and when i play that in my computer it is working fine.!

Help is appreciated..

Comment: It is not working in all the browsers .!   i think there is an issue with my javascript .that is why i have asked here @chris

Comment: After re-reading your question, I think it's the server side problem. Please show your upload script. I think you don't escape names properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just directly uploading video files and you don't convert or check them, you might face security issues.

At the same time it's not guaranteed that all uploaded files will play, due to variety of codecs. I'd recommend to perform the check-up on uploaded files to validate them as video and then convert.

---

The other possible reason why it could be happening, and like you mention, on some files, is that you don't escape URLs properly.

Try using `encodeURIComponent(path)` on returned URL.

> ***[encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)*** - The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

---

Besides, it might be the server-side issue. It's important to escape filenames properly on the server-side as well.

There are dozens of possible problems that can arise on files uploads and playing videos.

Comment: 1.Media resource `http://website.com/uploads/course_videos/Sentences/Sentences.mp4` could not be decoded.            
2.All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.

Comment: same issue eventhough i added this: `var path = encodeURIComponent(path);`

Comment: Can you open this link using browser?

Comment: I need to see the encoder string that is passed, I presume to `exec()`.

Comment: It is saying `video can't be played because the file is corrupt`              But actually the file is okay. And In chrome browser sometime audio also coming

Comment: Does it open in the same browser, using the link from the view page source? How does the link look on the source?

Comment: With inspect i can able to see that..  with view source data is not apending in that only my html is coming inside nothing is appending..

Comment: removed `type` still no luck see the screeshot it is saying like this: http://prntscr.com/exes40

Comment: What makes you think that you use valid codecs and/or video itself is valid?

Comment: Yes video is valid file.. mp4 file.. i have other files which are working with same codec..

Comment: What happens if you open the same file in the browser directly. Does it play?

Comment: Then file is corrupted or miss-encoded. I updated my answer. You would need to check and convert your videos to make it fail proof.

Comment: @llia i have tried that as well i have converted that in .mov .flv it is palying good in local but in application it is not playing.

Comment: What media player are you using? I would recommended mediaelementsjs.

Comment: sure i will give a try with that now.